# magento product thumbnail image cache issue

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 thumbnail main image cache path link changed from this link on the home page after 2 days
pub/media/catalog/product/cache/be293bf7411b924394287949fb9084eb/b/e/be-in-in.png

to this

media/catalog/product/cache/be293bf7411b924394287949fb9084eb/b/e/be-in-in.png

because of that, I am getting this

but when do flush Magento cache it changes back to

pub/media/catalog/product/cache/be293bf7411b924394287949fb9084eb/b/e/be-in-in.png

please can anyone give me suggestion to solve this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom module to be able to change the image path

Create that Block class and extend \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Image;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image

```
{
    public function _getUrl()
    {   
        $url = 'YourModulePath'.$this->getValue(); 
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: but i am not getting any issue on beta site this only happens after 2 or 3 days the image path is changed automatically

Comment: and this issue is only occur on home page  all other page is getting the image

Comment: The path containing the image is a fixed URL and it will not change unless you intervene and these links. You can check that the extensions you are using and especially the theme you are using are calling the correct image link.

Comment: the issue is images are not visible only on the homepage but visible on all  frontend pages

Comment: Have you deployed and re-run the indexer for your site? If not, please run the commands one by one: 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex